# Trigger in oracle SQL - Validation?

Tags: oracle, triggers

Hello guys I'm trying to create a trigger to validate some data, I've got a table called 'Events' and what I need to do create a trigger that will give me an error when you try to add an event in July.

`CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER concert_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON CONCERT
WHEN (event_date = 'July')
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE CONCERT
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_CONCERT CHECK (event.date ='July')
END;`

Here is the trigger that I have started that I think is the way to go but I'm not sure if this is right.

Thanks, Leprejohn

Comment: First, why do you want to use a trigger rather than a constraint?  If you can use a constraint, it's almost always a good idea to do that rather than using a trigger.  Second, your trigger is attempting to create a constraint-- that doesn't make sense.  A constraint is created once at installation time.  A trigger is fired every time an `INSERT` occurs.  It wouldn't make sense to create a constraint every time an `INSERT` occurs.  What is the data type of the `event_date` column?  Is it a `date`?  A `varchar2`?  Something else?

Comment: Hi Justin, its for a module that I'm doing and they want you to use a triggers not sure why but constraints seem a much better idea to do that on the creation of data or inserting the data type for the event_date column is date

Comment: "Module" here means "homework" right? If you're doing a homework assignment on triggers, I assume that the book will have a section discussing the difference between row-level triggers and statement-level triggers. You would need a row-level trigger to do data validation, the header you posted here is for a statement-level trigger. I assume that the book has also covered some introductory PL/SQL concepts-- you'll need an `IF` statement, you'll want to use `to_char` or `extract` to get the month from `event_date`, and you'll want to use `raise` or `raise_application_error` to throw an exception

Answer (score 2):

Since your classwork requires the use of a trigger you'd want to do something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CONCERT_BI
  BEFORE INSERT ON CONCERT
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF TO_CHAR(EVENT_DATE, 'MON') = 'JUL' THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20666, 'No concerts can be scheduled in July');
  END IF;
END CONCERT_BI;
```

Here I'm assuming that EVENT_DATE is an actual DATE instead of a character string; if that was a bad guess then change the comparison appropriately.